# SQL sorting with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

Tab1:

```
+------------+
| id | title |
+------------+
| 1 | B      |
| 2 | C      |
| 3 | A      |
| 4 | A      |
| 5 | A      |
| 6 | A      |
| ...        |
+------------+
```

Tab2:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| id | item_id | item_key |     item_value  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1       | value    | $4              |
| 2  | 1       | url      | http://h.com/   |
| 3  | 2       | value    | $5              |
| 4  | 3       | url      | http://i.com/   |
| 5  | 3       | value    | $1              |
| 6  | 3       | url      | http://y.com/   |
| 7  | 4       | value    | $2              |
| 8  | 4       | url      | http://z.com/   |
| 9  | 5       | value    | $1              |
| 10 | 5       | url      | http://123.com/ |
| ...                                       |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

- item_id is a foreign key from tab1.

How do I make it so I get a table of ids from Tab1 in order according to criteria from both tables. The criteria are the following:

- Order ASC by title. If title is the same,
- Order DESC by value. If both title and value is the same,
- Prioritize items who's 'url' key contains '123.com'.

The resulting table with the ordered results would be:

```
+------------+
| id | title |
+------------+
| 4 | A      |
| 5 | A      |
| 3 | A      |
| 6 | A      |
| 1 | B      |
| 2 | C      |
| ...        |
+------------+
```

The results should include items that don't have the one, both, or none of the fields from Tab2 set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, a simple join will do it. You'll have to join `Tab2` twice, since you want to order by values from both rows.

```
SELECT Tab1.id, Tab1.title
FROM Tab1
JOIN Tab2 t2_val ON t2_val.item_id = Tab1.id AND t2_val.item_key='value'
JOIN Tab2 t2_url ON t2_url.item_id = Tab1.id AND t2_url.item_key='url'
ORDER BY title, 
         t2_val.item_value DESC,
         t2_url.item_value LIKE '%123.com%' DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59ea2/6).

Comment: Any idea how to make it include in the results even those items from tab1 that don't have 'item_key' = 'value' or don't have 'item_key' = 'url' set in tab2?

Comment: @c10b10 Yes, plain [replacing `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c223/1) should do that, however your desired sort order doesn't tell what order to put them in if missing a row.

Comment: That's great because those items then are just left as last. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A little complicated, because when you do the `join` you will get multiple rows.  Here is an approach that aggregates `tab2` before doing the join:

```
select t1.*
from Tab1 t1 left outer join
     (select id,
             max(case when item_key = 'value' then item_value end) as value,
             max(case when item_key = 'url' then item_value end) as url
      from Tab2 t2
      group by id
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
order by t1.title, t2.value desc,
         (t2.url like '%123.com%') desc;
```

Comment: You are not giving me time to answer :) +1

Comment: Do you believe this to be faster than Joachim Isaksson's answer?

Comment: @c10b10 . . . That depends on a number of factors.  But, in general, MySQL performs joins better than aggregations.